# form to unsubscribe from a newsletter but from all

Tags: forms, newsletter

I wish to propose a form to allow a contact to unsubscribe from a newletter but not from the set to which it subscribes.

currently, the form I created unsubscribed from all newsletters.

It is possible? If yes, how ?

Comment: it would help if you explain what 'the form i created' actually means.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by directing folk to eg  www.yourdomain.org/civicrm/mailing/subscribe and if you have your Mailing List groups set up correctly (ie as public) then they should be able to unsub.

for folk using Drupal you can also do this via Webform

also review instructions at https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/set-up/

Comment: your welcome. StackExchange works best if you Accept answers and upvote them